# How to delete the oldest child in Firebase Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to limit the amount of data in my Firebase app by deleting the oldest child of a list every time a new one is added. I searched there is a JavaScript version of the answer and I would like to have android version of answer.

Here is my data structure:

```
   "team" : {
        "-KgoZM4NrImLNWVaUWks" : {
          "player_name" : "A",
          "timeStamp" : "1491235598092"
        },
        "-Kgo_2AkcqzoFr78lUUI" : {
          "player_name" : "B",
          "timeStamp" : "1491235778718"
        }
    }
```

I know how to query the oldest node but what should I do to remove the node?

```
Query find_old_node_query = mDatabase.child("team").orderByChild("timeStamp").limitToLast(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this query:
    `Query find_old_node_query = mDatabase.child("team").orderByChild("timeStamp").equalsTo(teamId);`

Where `teamId` is key that resulted when you used `push()` method to add the teams.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove node after get the node's push key in your callback

```
mDatabase.child("team").orderByChild("timeStamp").limitToLast(1).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  mDatabase.child("team").child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```